# Tunnel openwrt requests

Tags: proxy, openwrt

I am pretty new to OpenWrt what I want to achieve is the following scenario:

I have a socks5 proxy server running on a machine which is at work. From my home I wish to configure my router which is running OpenWrt to forward all connections to the socks5 proxy server

Is this possible using OpenWrt. If it is how can I do it ?

Comment: Do you want to forward specific ports or everything?

Comment: @slm for the beginning http traffic will do.The proxy I have is a socks5 proxy and I preffer to remain this way.

Comment: I think you want outgoing traffic from your home to be encapulated in the SOCKS protocol and redirected to your work proxy server. I don't know how to do this in OpenWRT - but if your computer at home is a Linux PC then check out the `tsocks` tool - if you type `tsocks` in front of your application name then all TCP connections will be "socksified" to the target proxy. Another tool is `proxychains`. Also investigate `tun2socks` which may work for OpenWRT (don't know) where it creates a tunnel interface that socksifies into which you could forward (using `iptables`) all traffic...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://newspaint.wordpress.com/2012/08/26/how-to-add-a-port-forward-using-the-web-interface-on-openwrt-10-03-1/). It's showing how to forward a port coming into the OpenWRT router from the outside (WAN) to inside (LAN), but if you look at this screenshot, you can see that you can specify the source as either WAN or LAN. So just select your source as LAN and specify the hostname/ip address of your socks5 proxy (basically do it backwards) to how the tutorial is showing how to set it up.

#### screenshot

[image: ss of firewall setup]

The tutorial's titled:

- [How To Add A Port Forward Using The Web Interface On OpenWrt 10.03.1](http://newspaint.wordpress.com/2012/08/26/how-to-add-a-port-forward-using-the-web-interface-on-openwrt-10-03-1/).